How to create tibble from a nested list, where one part of the list is nested slightly differently for some entries than for others
I am wondering how to create a tibble from a list, where one sublist contains another list of variables for some entries, while the same sublist contains only the variables for other entries. That is a bit vague, so I hope that the following example---which is based on this question (How to create data frame from list, selecting which sublist to focus on)---will help:
library(tidyverse)
listexample = list(books = list(list(
    title="Book 1",
    entry = "entry 1",
    publisher = "Books Unlimited",
    authors = list(
        list(name="bob", location="north dakota",
             subject = list(
                list(area="Fiction", abbrev="FI"),
                list(area="Mystery", abbrev="MY"))),
        list(name="susan", location="california",
             subject = list(area="Fiction", abbrev="FI")),
        list(name="tim",
             subject = list(
                list(area="Fiction", abbrev="FI"),
                list(area="Mystery", abbrev="MY"),
                list(area="Suspense", abbrev="SU")))),
    isbn = "1358",
    universities = list(
        list(univ="univ1"),
        list(univ="univ2"))
),
list(
    title="Book 2",
    entry = "entry 2",
    publisher = "Books Unified",
    authors = list(
        list(name="tom", location="north dakota",
             subject = list(
                        list(area="Fiction", abbrev="FI"),
                        list(area="Mystery", abbrev="MY"))),
        list(name="sally", location="california",
             subject = list(
                list(area="Nonfiction", abbrev="NF"),
                list(area="Biography", abbrev="BIO"))),
        list(name="erica", location="berlin",
              subject = list(area="Fiction", abbrev="FI"))),
    isbn = "1258",
    universities = list(
        list(univ="univ5"),
        list(univ="univ2"),
        list(univ="univ99"),
        list(univ="univ2"),
        list(univ="univ3"))
)   
),
misc = list(name="Jim Smith", location="Alaska"))

(To make the example make a bit more sense, think of an author's subject as the subject they usually write in, even if it differs from the subject of the particular book.)
The issue is that, within their subject list, some authors (bob, tim, tom, and sally) have two (or three) areas (each contained in a separate sublist), while other authors (susan and erica) have only one area (not contained in a separate sublist).
After modifying an answer from the question linked to above, I try:
listexample %>%
    .$books %>%
    tibblify %>%
    select(title, authors) %>%
    unnest(authors) %>% 
    unnest_wider(subject, names_sep="a")

This produces:
# A tibble: 6 × 8
  title  name  location     subjecta1        subjecta2        subjectaarea subjectaabbrev subjecta3       
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>        <list>           <list>           <chr>        <chr>          <list>          
1 Book 1 bob   north dakota <named list [2]> <named list [2]> NA           NA             <NULL>          
2 Book 1 susan california   <NULL>           <NULL>           Fiction      FI             <NULL>          
3 Book 1 tim   NA           <named list [2]> <named list [2]> NA           NA             <named list [2]>
4 Book 2 tom   north dakota <named list [2]> <named list [2]> NA           NA             <NULL>          
5 Book 2 sally california   <named list [2]> <named list [2]> NA           NA             <NULL>          
6 Book 2 erica berlin       <NULL>           <NULL>           Fiction      FI             <NULL> 

The issue is that the expansion shows susan and erica's entries in columns different from  for the other people. Let's say that I don't want to include the abbreviation column at all. How can I make it so that there are three columns subject1area, subject2area, and subject3area, so that the result looks like:
  title  name  location     subject1area        subject2area  subject3area     
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>        <chr>               <chr>         <chr>                
1 Book 1 bob   north dakota Fiction             Mystery       NA               
2 Book 1 susan california   Fiction             NA            NA
3 Book 1 tim   NA           Fiction             Mystery       Suspense           
4 Book 2 tom   north dakota Fiction             Mystery       NA               
5 Book 2 sally california   Nonfiction          Biography     NA            
6 Book 2 erica berlin       Fiction             NA            NA     


Since this is your second question on the topic, I would like to know how your unprocessed data looks like. Maybe there is a simpler way? I think that collapse::unlist2d() or similar functions might help, but have not found a good, i.e. no hard-coded, solution.

@Friede, the unprocessed data is Scopus data from the rscopus package, in particular the get_complete_author_info function (or other related functions). If you go to https://dev.elsevier.com/scopus.html#!/Author_Search/AuthorSearch, you can play around with the examples to get a general sense of how the data looks.

I.e. listexample is an output example of your API request?

No, it is not from the API request (I didn't want to use the actual data as it requires a token), but shares a similar format, at least in some ways.

The attempt in the question is actually quite close.  The lines below are the same as there except for adding (1) the mutate line which regularizes the varying depth subject column so that it can be processed uniformly by unnest_wider and the (2) rename_with line which ensures the column names are as in the question.
listexample %>%
  .$book %>%
  tibblify %>% 
  select(title, authors) %>%
  unnest(authors) %>%
  mutate(subject = lapply(subject, \(x) bind_rows(x)[["area"]])) %>%
  unnest_wider(subject, names_sep = "a") %>%
  rename_with(~ sub("subjecta(\\d+)", "subject\\1area", .x))

giving
# A tibble: 6 × 6
  title  name  location     subject1area subject2area subject3area
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       
1 Book 1 bob   north dakota Fiction      Mystery      <NA>        
2 Book 1 susan california   Fiction      <NA>         <NA>        
3 Book 1 tim   <NA>         Fiction      Mystery      Suspense    
4 Book 2 tom   north dakota Fiction      Mystery      <NA>        
5 Book 2 sally california   Nonfiction   Biography    <NA>        
6 Book 2 erica berlin       Fiction      <NA>         <NA>        


Ah, clever to do the l_apply/bind_rows step.

It seems like the named lists are causing you problems, because some of them are named, and some of them aren't. We just need to turn our named lists into the same format unnamed lists.
tibble(books = listexample$books) %>%
  unnest_wider(books) %>%
  select(title, authors) %>%
  unnest_longer(authors) %>%
  unnest_wider(authors) %>%
  # if it is named let's get the area
  mutate(subject = 
    map_if(
      subject, 
      ~ !is.null(names(.x)), 
      ~ list(pluck(.x, "area"))
    )
  ) %>%
  # unnest like normal, setting NA as default
  unnest_wider(
    subject, 
    names_sep = "area", 
    transform = ~ pluck(.x, 1, .default = NA)
  )

#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>   title  name  location     subjectarea1 subjectarea2 subjectarea3
#>   <chr>  <chr> <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       
#> 1 Book 1 bob   north dakota Fiction      Mystery      NA    
#> 2 Book 1 susan california   Fiction      NA           NA    
#> 3 Book 1 tim   NA           Fiction      Mystery      Suspense    
#> 4 Book 2 tom   north dakota Fiction      Mystery      NA    
#> 5 Book 2 sally california   Nonfiction   Biography    NA    
#> 6 Book 2 erica berlin       Fiction      NA           NA   


Good approach - thanks!

This approach is more than ugly. I will come back later. However, I suspect there should be a concise way to solve the puzzle with the arguments of tidyr::pivot_wider(), which also allows us to get rid of the sapply/lapply:
cbind(title = rep(sapply(o <- listexample[[1]], \(i) i$title), 
              sapply(o, \(i) lengths(i["authors"]))),
      lapply(lapply(o, \(i) i[names(i) %in% c("authors")]), \(i) {
        rrapply::rrapply(i, how = "melt") |>
          dplyr::select(L2, L3, L4, L5, value) |>
          tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = L2, names_from = L3:L5, 
                             values_from = value) } ) |> 
        dplyr::bind_rows() |>
        select(name_NA_NA, location_NA_NA,subject_1_area, 
               subject_area_NA, subject_2_area,subject_3_area)) |> 
  tidyr::unite(subject_1_area, c(subject_1_area, subject_area_NA),
  na.rm = TRUE, remove = TRUE) |>
  dplyr::rename(name = name_NA_NA, location = location_NA_NA)

giving
   title  name     location subject_1_area subject_2_area subject_3_area
1 Book 1   bob north dakota      Fiction        Mystery           <NA>
2 Book 1 susan   california      Fiction           <NA>           <NA>
3 Book 1   tim         <NA>      Fiction        Mystery       Suspense
4 Book 2   tom north dakota      Fiction        Mystery           <NA>
5 Book 2 sally   california   Nonfiction      Biography           <NA>
6 Book 2 erica       berlin      Fiction           <NA>           <NA>


Thanks for the answer! I didn't know about one of the functions you used, so good to have them on my radar.

Here is an alternative approach where the book and author/subject entries are expanded into two separate tables, which are then merged back together:
library(rrapply)
library(data.table)

## expand book title table
books <- rrapply(listexample, condition = \(x, .xname) .xname %in% c("title", "entry", "publisher", "isbn"), how = "bind", options = list(coldepth = 3, namecols = TRUE))

## expand author/subject table
author_subject <- rrapply(listexample, condition = \(x, .xname) .xname %in% c("name", "location", "area"), how = "bind", options = list(coldepth = 5, namecols = TRUE))

## merge tables
books_author_subject <- merge(as.data.table(books), as.data.table(author_subject), all = TRUE)

## select/coalesce relevant columns
books_author_subject[, .(title, entry, publisher, isbn, name, subject.1.area = fcoalesce(subject.area, subject.1.area), subject.2.area, subject.3.area)]

#>     title   entry       publisher   isbn   name subject.1.area subject.2.area subject.3.area
#>    <char>  <char>          <char> <char> <char>         <char>         <char>         <char>
#> 1: Book 1 entry 1 Books Unlimited   1358    bob        Fiction        Mystery           <NA>
#> 2: Book 1 entry 1 Books Unlimited   1358  susan        Fiction           <NA>           <NA>
#> 3: Book 1 entry 1 Books Unlimited   1358    tim        Fiction        Mystery       Suspense
#> 4: Book 2 entry 2   Books Unified   1258    tom        Fiction        Mystery           <NA>
#> 5: Book 2 entry 2   Books Unified   1258  sally     Nonfiction      Biography           <NA>
#> 6: Book 2 entry 2   Books Unified   1258  erica        Fiction           <NA>           <NA>


Very good - thank you!
